# Error when importing beautifulsoup4 in python 3.5 in jupyter

Tags: beautifulsoup, python-3.5

In yupyter I am trying to import bs4 but I get an error :

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/bs4/builder/__init__.py in HTMLTreeBuilder()
232     """
233 
--> 234     preserve_whitespace_tags = HTMLAwareEntitySubstitution.preserve_whitespace_tags
    235     empty_element_tags = set([
    236         # These are from HTML5.

AttributeError: type object 'HTMLAwareEntitySubstitution' has no attribute 'preserve_whitespace_tags'
```

I uninstalled completely bs4 and html5lib than reinstalled them again still throwing the same error.
Searched everywhere for such a problem couldn't find a solution.
If someone can help, I would appreciate it a lot

Strange thing is that I don't have this error when I use atom.

Answer (score 1):

From [AttributeError: type object 'HTMLAwareEntitySubstitution' has no attribute... Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/beautifulsoup/bTsxrbEIuVo/flGVVXquBgAJ):

- Either try opening the Jupyter notebook in Canopy, or
- Force downgrade html5lib to an older version:

```
pip install --upgrade html5lib==1.0b8
```